# OpenNI2 project with CMake weird sintax error with uint16_t

Tags: visual-studio-2008, cmake, openni

I made a CMake project for using **OpenNI2** and **NITE2** following the usual steps. CMake is able to find the paths for includes and libs of both NITE and OpenNI. The project in visual studio links the libs and includes properly.

So far everything looks right, but when I compile (no linking errors) I get weird sintax error with the file OnyCTypes.h. Errors are like:

```
Error1 error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'usbVendorId'  c:\program files (x86)\openni2\include\OniCTypes.h  84
```

I also copied the folder **Openni/Redist** contents to the same folder of the Visual Studio project, so I cannot guess what is causing the error.

What else can I check? Anybody had a similar error with OpenNI2?

Comment: Are you in Windows or Linux? What is your Visual Studio Version/Eclipse??

Comment: I am using VisualStudio2008

Answer (score 4, accepted):

uint16_t belong to stdint.h [Take a Look](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__stdint.html)

This library is not included in VS2008 by default, download it and include it in the CMake to run the project without the linking problem.

Comment: that was it, there are some ifdefs in OpenNI headers that check visual studio version for including that file, but there is no definition of the type uin16_t, so the only solution is to download stdint.h. Weird error...